# Creating an SQL query to show summarized data from different tables

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a report for Microsoft Dynamics CRM.  We want it to show orders created in the last 30 days, as well as who the order is for and some financial information (revenue of that order, total cost of the products, gross profit)

Unfortunately the data is very scattered through the SQL database.  The only place where the unit cost appears is in Sales Order Detail (it's actually a custom field I created), while the rest of the information I need is in the header (called Sales Order Base and also Sales Order Extension Base for the custom fields)

Here's what I have right now, which works in Microsoft SQL Server:

```
SELECT
  SalesOrderBase.SalesOrderId AS [SalesOrderBase SalesOrderId]
  ,SalesOrderBase.Name
  ,SalesOrderBase.CustomerIdName
  ,AccountBase.Name
  ,SalesOrderBase.TotalAmountLessFreight
  ,SystemUserBase.FullName
FROM
  SalesOrderBase
  INNER JOIN SalesOrderExtensionBase
    ON SalesOrderBase.SalesOrderId = SalesOrderExtensionBase.SalesOrderId
  INNER JOIN AccountBase
    ON SalesOrderExtensionBase.new_ParentCustomer = AccountBase.AccountId
  INNER JOIN SystemUserBase
    ON SalesOrderBase.OwnerId = SystemUserBase.SystemUserId
--  INNER JOIN SalesOrderDetailBase
--  ON SalesOrderBase.SalesOrderId = SalesOrderDetailBase.SalesOrderId
WHERE
  SalesOrderBase.CreatedOn >= DATEADD(day,-30, getdate())
```

Now, you can see the section I commented out.  The problem is that if I use an Inner Join to connect the Sales Order (header) to the detail (items), I get duplicate results.  Each item in the order shows up on its own line, which is NOT what I want!

I did some playing around with the SUM function and got a rudimentary query like this to work:

```
SELECT SUM(ExtendedAmount)
  FROM [dbo].[SalesOrderDetailBase],

WHERE SalesOrderId = '{a GUID that I would type in for testing}'
```

What I need help with is combining these two.  I need the SalesOrderId to use the one in a particular row, but simply give me the sum instead of one row per value.  I'm using "Extended Amount" because the "Extended Amount" from the items is equal to the "total amount less freight" from the header - it's a good way to check that the function is working.  I'll change it to the cost/profit fields once I get it to work.

I thought UNION might help me here, but after doing some research I can see that it's more like an "AND" statement, and only shows values which are returned by two separate queries. That's not what I want at all... I just want to add a column to the results that grabs a sum of a value in another table.

Once again, this is Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL.

Thanks

Comment: Its not clear to me what you are asking for. Your best bet is to provide the DDL for the involved tables, some sample data, the expected results from the query, and the query you have so far (*which you did provide*).

Comment: Although maybe all you need is a [GROUP BY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx), not sure if that is what your are eluding to?

Comment: Yes, it looks like that's all I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure you just need to include your SUM and a group by. I cleaned up your query formatting and added some aliases to make things a lot easier to maintain. This should be pretty close.

```
SELECT
    sob.SalesOrderId AS [SalesOrderBase SalesOrderId]
    , sob.Name
    , sob.CustomerIdName
    , ab.Name
    , sob.TotalAmountLessFreight
    , sub.FullName
    ,  SUM(sodb. ExtendedAmount) as ExtendedAmountTotal
FROM SalesOrderBase sob
INNER JOIN SalesOrderExtensionBase soeb ON sob.SalesOrderId = soeb.SalesOrderId
INNER JOIN AccountBase ab ON soeb.new_ParentCustomer = ab.AccountId
INNER JOIN SystemUserBase sub ON sob.OwnerId = sub.SystemUserId
INNER JOIN SalesOrderDetailBase sodb ON sob.SalesOrderId = sodb.SalesOrderId
WHERE sob.CreatedOn >= DATEADD(day, -30, getdate()) 
GROUP BY sob.SalesOrderId
    , sob.Name
    , sob.CustomerIdName
    , ab.Name
    , sob.TotalAmountLessFreight
    , sub.FullName
```

Comment: Ah, so the missing link was just the GROUP BY? That works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: If this worked you should consider marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Again, not very clear what you are asking for but what I think you are getting it is you want a group by like so.

```
SELECT
  SalesOrderBase.SalesOrderId AS [SalesOrderBase SalesOrderId]
  ,SalesOrderBase.Name
  ,SalesOrderBase.CustomerIdName
  ,AccountBase.Name
  ,SalesOrderBase.TotalAmountLessFreight
  ,SystemUserBase.FullName
  ,SUM(SalesOrderDetailBase.ExtendedAmount) AS ExtendedAmount
FROM
  SalesOrderBase
  INNER JOIN SalesOrderExtensionBase
    ON SalesOrderBase.SalesOrderId = SalesOrderExtensionBase.SalesOrderId
  INNER JOIN AccountBase
    ON SalesOrderExtensionBase.new_ParentCustomer = AccountBase.AccountId
  INNER JOIN SystemUserBase
    ON SalesOrderBase.OwnerId = SystemUserBase.SystemUserId
  INNER JOIN SalesOrderDetailBase
    ON SalesOrderBase.SalesOrderId = SalesOrderDetailBase.SalesOrderId
WHERE
  SalesOrderBase.CreatedOn >= DATEADD(day,-30, getdate())
GROUP BY SalesOrderBase.SalesOrderId
  ,SalesOrderBase.Name
  ,SalesOrderBase.CustomerIdName
  ,AccountBase.Name
  ,SalesOrderBase.TotalAmountLessFreight
  ,SystemUserBase.FullName
```